# unable to build the source code - fatal error RC1015 : cannot open include file 'res\XXXX.rc2'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, include-path

Steps tried to resolve this issue

1. Add the path in the project properties dialog. The path must be added in Configuration Properties -> Resources -> General ->
   "Additional Standard Include Path".
2. set the path for the preprocessor to search for these include files.
   set the path in Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories
       -> Additional Include Directories. Both are found in project settings.
3. Right click project -> Add -> existing item -> file include to it,
   checked the source code with the VS2013 professional,VS2008 &
       VS2012 also.
4. RC1015 can occur even if the include file exists in a directory
   specified as an Additional Include Directory in the Configuration
       Properties -> Resources -> General property page; specify the
       complete path to the include file.
5. If the Include Path is very long, please remove some of the Include paths: 1. On the Tools menu, click Options. 2. In the left pane of the Options dialog box, click the Projects folder, and then click VC++ Directories. 3. In the Show directories for list, click Include files. 4. In the lower window, delete some of the paths, and then click OK.
6. Tried after uninstall/reinstall the VS2008

please can anyone help me to solve this problem. I have tried almost everything that I have seen on the internet.

Comment: I found that those files are missing in my project folder. Created those files  and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I started getting it when I added some controls to a dialog box for a GUI application. The way I fixed it is by editing the .rc file. There should be an include that is pointing to res/x.rc2.

Remove the res/ prefix. That should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming windows kit is installed. I solved l error RC1015 using and running the vcvars32.bat file in command line environment which is found in the bin directory under the VC installation directory.or use everything tool to find it. It's limited to setting the appropriate environment variables to enable 32-bit x86 command-line builds. It's the equivalent of the vcvarsall x86 command. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396